# How to add customer field in "Recurring Payments Dashboard"?

Tags: paypal

I have been trying to add a unique identifier to the "Customer" field when viewing Paypal's "Recurring Payments Dashboard" page, however the field seems to be blank regardless of what I submit when creating the payment profile.

I am using the `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` method.  Logically, I would assume this field to either be `PAYERID`, or `SUBSCRIBERNAME`, however they do not show up on this column when I supply values.  Any insight as to what parameter I'm looking for here?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the variable "SUBSCRIBERNAME" in the "CreateRecurringProfile" API call to display the value in the customer field on the Recurring Payment Dashboard . I tried to create a profile by passing this variable and it is displaying correctly on dashboard .

```
VERSION = 109.0
METHOD = CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile
TOKEN =  EC-5SA27721K1062883U 
**SUBSCRIBERNAME = MR ESHAN SUBSCRIBER**
PROFILESTARTDATE = 2014-10-06T00:00:00Z
PROFILEREFERENCE = THIS IS PROFLIE REF
```

[image]